# Facebook Graph API - Access Posts from Public Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a Facebook app and I am trying to use this app to fetch comments on posts on Public Pages. When I am using the Graph API Explorer Tool, using the App Token, it returns an OAuthException. It says I need the pages_read_engagement permission or the 'Page Public Content' feature.

My problem is to request those permission, I need my app to be working. How am I suppose to get it working if I don't have those permissions?

[Graph API Explorer Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VF98.png)

Comment: Test with a page you have admin access to, and an admin user access token or a page token, first, then submit for review.

Comment: yeah, right. I didn't thought of that. thanks, @CBroe! Great help.